# Rspec Factory Girl testing class methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to Rspec and Factory Girl. I'm using it to test models that already exist. Is there a way to test existing class methods from the original model in apps/model directory using the copies generated by Factory Girl?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just create your spec file in the spec/models directory.

Here's an example `certificate_spec.rb` file for a `Certificate` model that should validate that a certificate has a `first_name`.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Certificate" do
  let(:certificate) { FactoryGirl.build(:certificate) }

  it "is valid with valid attributes" do
    expect(certificate).to be_valid
  end

  it "is not valid without a first name" do
    certificate.firstname_a = nil
    expect(certificate).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

To test a specific class method, set up your model as you need, either with a factory or by creating an instance from a factory and modifying it.

Then just call the method you need on the instance:

```
it "should respond to #doSomething with true" do
  expect(certificate.doSomething).to be_true
end
```

### Update

As pointed out by Junchao Gu, I have not provided an example of testing class methods above.

By definition, class methods are defined on the class rather than any instance of it. As such, you do not need any instances created by FactoryGirl in order to be able to test class methods. Simply set your expectations against the class.

For example, lets say a `User` class provides a list of roles which users could be a member of. You might want to ensure those roles are defined in a certain way:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User" do
  describe ".available_roles" do
    it "should return anonymous, member, moderator, admin in that order" do
      expect(User.available_roles).to_equal %w{anonymous member moderator admin}
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the expecation was against the `User` class, not against an instance of it.

Comment: I am new to rspec + factorygirl too. but I am pretty sure that neither of your examples are "Class methods"